# "New version of BigQuery" Message

Tags: google-bigquery

Last few days I am getting below message in BigQuery UI few times a day.
Nothing really new that I was able to catch.
Anyone has same experience?
Any idea what is this?

[image: New version of BigQuery??]

Comment: There has not been a new rollout since August iirc, however If you are only a BigQuery user then this will be a new version of Google Cloud Console available to you.

Comment: That is exactly why I am curious of what this can be? :o)

Comment: BigQuery actually releases minor updates approximately weekly, but we don't make a big announcement for every one. This message just tells you that you can reload to get the newest web UI updates.

Comment: Ok. Got it. I have never seen such message before in last at least year. That is why i asked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message indicates that there is a new version of the BigQuery web UI available, but that you need to click "Reload" in your browser in order to get the new code.

Note that you get backend updates automatically--this applies to the web UI only.

Comment: as I mentioned  - Nothing really new that I was able to catch! any examples of what is new? i am/was getting this message for last few days

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see major changes--these are minor incremental updates. We're also considering raising the threshold for showing this warning so that you don't see it quite as often.